# Appropriate translation of "puer territus pedes nudos aspicit"?

Tags: lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

I'm working through LLPSI, and there's a clause in chapter 24 that I feel like I'm not getting the right meaning out of.

In context, the clause "puer territus pedes nudos aspicit" is about a boy who injured his foot on a prior day and has been unable to sleep. When he wakes he is discouraged to see his foot has swollen considerably.

My read of this sentence is "the frightened boy sees his bare feet." However, in context this doesn't quite make sense to me. At this point in the story there has been no mention of him being frightened, but if it were to read "the boy is frightened WHEN he sees his bare foot" or "the boy becomes frightened seeing his bare foot" it would make sense. Hence, I wonder if I'm misunderstanding the vocabulary or grammar.

You can see the full context here, on line 5 (which is read at about the 40 second mark).
https://youtu.be/QBw3kPSwsUA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you've understood the construction: the frightened boy looks at his bare feet. I'm not sure what's confusing about the context, though; the preceding line:

> Itaque e lecto surgere conatur, sed pes denuo dolere incipit.

He tries to get up out of the bed, but his foot begins hurting again. This is what frightens him and causes him to look at his feet. When he subsequently sees that one of his feet is swollen and bigger than the other, he merely marvels:

> Quintus miratur quod pedes, qui heri pares erant, hodie tam impares sunt.

It's the pain that causes his fear.

Comment: It makes perfect sense now that I hear you explain it. Thank you!